# Is There a declval for Function Pointers?

Tags: c++, function-pointers, sfinae, return-type, declval

I have a function and I need to test whether I can pass an argument of a given type to it. For example:

```
template<typename T, auto F>
decltype(F(declval<T>{})) foo();
```

Calling `foo<int, bar>()` does 2 things:

1. Sets the return type of `foo` would have the same return type as `bar`
2. Ensures that `bar` is a function that accepts an argument of
   type `T`

Unfortunately I don't have access to `auto` template types, but I still want to accomplish both of these. What I need is a `decltype` for function pointers, which would allow me to do something like this:

```
template <typename T, typename F>
decltype(declval<F>(declval<T>{})) foo();
```

So I could still call `foo<int, bar>()` and get the same result. Of course there isn't a `declval` for function pointers. But is there another way I could accomplish this?

Comment: `declval` works on any type, including function pointers.

Comment: Would you be okay with `foo<int, decltype(&bar), bar>()`?

Comment: ... or `std::function`s :/

Comment: @NathanOliver that's what I have right now. That was what we did before `auto` I guess... but not my desired solution.

Comment: @YSC I'm not certain how I could use a `std::function` to work around this?

Comment: Do you need the actual function pointer passed to the function?  Does the pointer need to be known at compile time?

Comment: @NathanOliver Nope, I'm fine with the struck through code in my question. I just need to match the return type of `bar`. Using `auto` just let me call `decltype` on `F`.

Comment: Okay.  Did the second example fail to compile for you, as it should work?  `declval` works on all types as pointed out in Guillaume Racicot's answer.

Comment: @NathanOliver I was missing the constructor on `declval`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Of course there isn't a declval for function pointers.

What do you mean? `std::declval` works perfectly with function pointer types:

```
template<typename F, typename... Args>
using call_t = decltype(std::declval<F>()(std::declval<Args>()...));
```

In this example, `F` can be a function pointer type, a lambda type or any callable types.

Here's an example of usage:

```
template<typename T, typename F>
auto foo() -> call_t<F, T>;
```

Another example using the detection idiom (implementable in C++11):

```
template<typename F, typename... Args>
using is_callable = is_detected<call_t, F, Args...>;

static_assert(is_callable<void(*)(int), int>::value, "callable")
```

---

Note that all this can be replaced by `std::invoke_result_t` and `std::is_invocable` in C++17. I'd suggest mimicking those to have the most seamless upgrade.

Comment: The problem with this is the OP doesn't have an actual function pointer to use in the function.  They still have to get that in there somehow.

Comment: If I look at it's two requirements, he don't need the actual function pointer value

Comment: Looks like you're right.  Not sure why the OP thinks it doesn't work.

Comment: @NathanOliver This has my +1 it does work just not for me in Visual Studio, but I tested in g++ and that does work. I'll post a follow up question... Also if no one can give me a cross platform solution I will accept this.

Comment: @JonathanMee can you create a compiler explorer example that reproduce your error? This code should be cross platform.

Comment: @NathanOliver So my example is a little more involved. I think the problem is nesting `using` statements on VisualStudio: https://stackoverflow.com/q/54949124/2642059

Comment: @GuillaumeRacicot You're right this is an excellent answer and _should_ be cross platform... but for VisualStudio bugs.