# Templated usings Can't be Nested in Visual Studio

Tags: c++, templates, visual-studio-2017, using, return-type

This is about as simplified as I could make a toy example that still hit the bug:

```
struct Vector3f64 {
    double x;
    double y;
    double z;
};

struct Vector3f32 {
    float x;
    float y;
    float z;
};

// I use this to select their element type in functions:
template <typename T>
using param_vector = std::conditional_t<std::is_same_v<std::remove_const_t<std::remove_reference_t<T>>, Vector3f64>, double, float>;

// This is the function I want to pull the return type from:
template <typename T>
T VectorVolume(const T x, const T y, const T z) {
    return x * x + y * y + z * z;
}

template<typename F, typename T>
using call_t = decltype(std::declval<F>()(std::declval<T>(), std::declval<T>(), std::declval<T>()));

// This function fails to compile:
template <typename T>
call_t<decltype(&VectorVolume<param_vector<T>>), param_vector<T>> func(const T& param) {
    return VectorVolume(param.x, param.y, param.z);
}

int main() {
    const Vector3f64 foo{ 10.0, 10.0, 10.0 };

    std::cout << func(foo) << std::endl;
}
```

The `call_t` is from [Guillaume Racicot's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54947576/2642059) which I wanted to use to find a return type. But I get this error from [visual-studio-2017](/questions/tagged/visual-studio-2017) version 15.6.7:

```
error C2064: term does not evaluate to a function taking 3 arguments<br>
note: see reference to alias template instantiation 'call_t<unknown-type,double>' being compiled
note: see reference to function template instantiation 'unknown-type func(const T &)' being compiled
```

This works fine on g++: https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/48b18b66c39486ef It'll even work fine on [visual-studio-2017](/questions/tagged/visual-studio-2017) if I don't pass one `using` statement to another:

```
template <typename T>
call_t<decltype(&VectorVolume<param_vector<T>>), double> func(const T& param) {
    return VectorVolume(param.x, param.y, param.z);
}
```

Is there a way I can work around this?

Comment: Can you please stitch this together into a single copyable code block we can copy and paste?

Comment: @NathanOliver Could you use the Live Example to copy from: https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/48b18b66c39486ef I found the comments to be helpful. If that's not sufficient I suppose I could rework.

Comment: Probably Microsoft tries to ignore such totally unreadable code ;-)

Comment: Version 15.9.5 compiles successfully so it is probably a bug that was fixed.

Comment: You shouldn't put you MCVE behind a link.  What if the link is blocked for people?

Comment: @NathanOliver Yeah :( I'm required to stay on this version. Don't suppose there's an easy workaround?

Comment: @NathanOliver OK put my comments in as... comments... That should be copy-pastable.

Comment: @JonathanMee I could find a workaround but I don't have visual studio 15.6 right now. Is there a way I could test that with an online compiler? Compiler explorer don't have that particular version.

Comment: @GuillaumeRacicot I actually used the `invoke_result` hint on the end of your answer to solve this locally: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54950469/2642059 I think your answer got me all the way there, I just didn't know it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[As mentioned by @NathanOliver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54949124/templated-usings-cant-be-nested-in-visual-studio#comment96661130_54949124) the right solution is to upgrade to 15.9.5 where this is fixed. But barring that you can use [`result_of` or `invoke_result`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/result_of) to solve that on 15.6.7 by changing `call_t` to:

```
template<typename F, typename T>
using call_t = result_of_t<F&&(T, T, T)>;
```

Note that `result_of` is deprecated in [c++17](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b17) so if you are running with "/std:c++17" or "/std:c++latest" this won't work, you'll need to use the more convenient:

```
template<typename F, typename T>
using call_t = invoke_result_t<F, T, T, T>;
```

It's worth noting that [Guillaume Racicot's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54947576/2642059) used an elegant veradic template, which also works respectively as: `template <typename F, typename... Args> using call_t = result_of_t<F&&(Args&&...)>` or `template<typename F, typename... Args> using call_t = invoke_result_t<F, Args...>;` if you change your definition of `func` to:

```
template <typename T>
call_t<decltype(&VectorVolume<param_vector<T>>), param_vector<T>, param_vector<T>, param_vector<T>> func(const T& param) {
    return VectorVolume(param.x, param.y, param.z);
}
```