# Working Around a Visual Studio Internal Compiler Error With Nested Templated Variables

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2017, function-parameter, template-variables, internal-compiler-error

I'm trying to write code that will let me index into the parameter types of a function:

```
template <typename R, typename... ARGS>
R function_return(R(*)(ARGS...));

template <typename R, typename... ARGS>
std::tuple<ARGS...> function_parameters(R(*)(ARGS...));

template <int I, typename T>
using get_type = typename std::conditional_t<(I < 0), std::tuple_element<static_cast<int>(std::tuple_size_v<T>) + I, T>, std::tuple_element<I, T>>::type;

template <int I, typename T>
using parameter_type = get_type<I, decltype(function_parameters(std::declval<T>()))>;
```

[<kbd>Live Example (ICE under VS)</kbd>](https://godbolt.org/z/08_Mmz)
[<kbd>Live Example (working on GCC)</kbd>](https://ideone.com/oA1TLg)

But when I try to use this on [visual-studio-2017](/questions/tagged/visual-studio-2017) I get an internal compiler error:

> fatal error C1001: An internal error has occurred in the compiler.

Is there another way that I can do this which might work around the internal compiler error?

Comment: Filed a bug ticket already? That said, there's one thing in your code that I'd avoid: Use of `ALL_UPPERCASE` for regular identifiers. If any win32 header somehow leaks into that code, you get a bunch of macros with that and some of them are plain evil.

Comment: Definitely. Prefer `ReturnType` and `ArgType` or something like that

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt The live example gives output and obvs doesn't ICE. The bug is in VS not in GCC 6.3

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt That is the correct behavior. I'm just demonstrating that I'm writing good code as far as gcc is concerned. The ICE is only on VS2017.

Comment: Gotta say, though, [it works for me](https://godbolt.org/z/0lLJ75).

Comment: You can show the example on godbolt.org or upload to some other online compiler site that actually uses MSVC.

Comment: Ah, 19.15 breaks though (and 19.16 times out)

Comment: Can you upgrade to VS2019? :D

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Perhaps it is a subversion issue. I'm stuck on 15.6.7.

Comment: It absolutely is so, as shown. (You really mean 19.13, [the version number of the compiler itself](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Visual_C%2B%2B#Internal_version_numbering) rather than of the IDE)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [mentioned here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54949124/2642059) it seems like [visual-studio-2017](/questions/tagged/visual-studio-2017) struggles with templated using statements being passed to each other. (I'm seeing the internal compiler error on 15.6.7; as [mentioned here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56379486/working-around-a-visual-studio-internal-compiler-error-with-nested-templated-var/56379824#comment99359847_56379486) this may have been fixed by patches.)

I've been able to work around it by capturing all the functionality in a single using statement:

```
template <typename R, typename... ARGS>
R function_return(R(*)(ARGS...));

template <typename R, typename... ARGS>
std::tuple<ARGS...> function_parameters(R(*)(ARGS...));

template <int I, typename T, typename X = decltype(function_parameters(std::declval<T>()))>
using parameter_type = typename std::conditional_t<(I < 0), std::tuple_element<static_cast<int>(std::tuple_size_v<X>) + I, X>, std::tuple_element<I, X>>::type;
```

Answer (score 2):

It probably depends on the exact (sub)version of VS2017, as mine does not produce an ICE on the code. However, the code is still problematic, as it can potentially instantiate `std::tuple_element<2147483647, T>` or something similar. You need to make sure only the correct branch is ever evaluated. Replace your definition of `get_type` with this:

```
template <int I, typename T, bool negative = (I < 0)>
struct get_type_impl;

template <int I, typename T>
struct get_type_impl<I, T, true>
{
  using type = typename std::tuple_element<static_cast<int>(std::tuple_size<T>::value) + I, T>::type;
};

template <int I, typename T>
struct get_type_impl<I, T, false>
{
  using type = typename std::tuple_element<I, T>::type;
};

template <int I, typename T>
using get_type = typename get_type_impl<I, T>::type;
```

This works for me on my VS 2017 (cl version 19.12)

Comment: Can confirm [this fixes the problem on the affected version](https://godbolt.org/z/QBP2JL). Good job!